# Java Netbeans MySql database Connection

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I want to insert row into MySql database with a normal Program for Mysql connection in Java Netbeans,but when i run this code my database remains unaffected.I had setup connection with Netbeans and Mysql and it is working fine.

Code:

```
    import java.sql.*;

    public class MySqlConnection {


       static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
       static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/migration";
       static final String USER = "root";
       static final String PASS = "ngts12345";

       public static void main(String[] args) {

            Connection conn = null;

            try{
             Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
             System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
             conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
             System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");
             System.out.println("Inserting records into the table...");

             String sql = "INSERT INTO document (document_id, document_name, format)" +
            "VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
             PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
             preparedStatement.setInt(1, 1);
             preparedStatement.setString(2, "Test2");
             preparedStatement.setString(3, "Test3");
             preparedStatement.executeUpdate(); 
             preparedStatement.close();  
             conn.close();  
        }catch(SQLException se){
          //Handle errors for JDBC

       }catch(Exception e){
          //Handle errors for Class.forName

       }
     }
  }
```

Comment: have u checked the log?

Answer (score 0):

there is not space after `format)` and `values`

Change this line to

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO document (document_id, document_name, format)" +
        "VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
```

to

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO document(document_id, document_name, format) " +
        "VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
preparedStatement.executeUpdate(sql);
```

and you should also specify database

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO database_name.document (document_id, document_name, format)" +"VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try{      
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); // MySQL database  connection
  conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306","root","");
  String sql = "select * from 'table_name'.database_name where user=? and pass=?";
  pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
  rs= pst.executeQuery();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Note preparedStatement.executeUpdate() returns true (record was successful in insert, update, or delete) or false (not successful). Therefore I suggest printing out the result to see if it worked.
 
As for not getting an error message, are you consuming exceptions and not printing out the error? In your catch block, put e.printStackTrace() to see what the error is.

Comment: [executeUpdate()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate()) returns int not boolean(true or false)